# Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spaces') npm run serve vue

Tags: vue.js, npm

Hi i'm facing somewhat a strange problem during `$npm run serve`

[image]

here is my page structure

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: 'game',
   ...
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
 $variable1:#fff;
 ....
</style>
```

My `package.json` looks something like this

```
"devDependencies":{
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "vue-loader-v16": "npm:vue-loader@^16.1.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally this kind of error happens when you try to access a property of an object that does not (yet) exist.

So I think somewhere in your code you try to access someObject.spaces but someObject is undefined. To avoid this, you can add a simple if-clause before your operation:

```
if(someObject){
  doSomething(someObject.spaces)
}
```

I think you'll have to fill in more code to identify exactly what happens, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check your styles
U should use

`::v-deep() { a { color: red; }}`

instead of

`::v-deep { a { color: red; }}`

more info https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4745

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not define the state in the right way

I suppose that somewhere you call `spaces` like this `game.spaces` with defining `game: undefined`. The right way to define the game state with a default value is an empty object like this:

```
<script>
export default {
   name: 'game',
   data(){
      game: {}
   }
}
</script>
```

Or You can use `?.` Optional chaining to avoid this error like `game?.spaces`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining